# See ending of div visual studio code

Tags: html, visual-studio

Is there a better way to see the ending of an div just like in inspect element inside chrome and firefox? I find it very easy as overview like this!

[image: example ending div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with VS plugin called [Highlight Matching Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag)